# Solve for $N(t)$ (seperation of variables)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Related to Bernoulli smallpox model

$\frac{dN(t)}{dt}=-\mu N(t)-\gamma N_0 e^{-(\mu +1)t}$ with initial condition $N_0=N(0)$

I rearrange it as

$\frac{dN(t)}{dt}+\mu N(t)=-\gamma N_0 e^{-(\mu +1)t}$ then what...

Comment: Use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) or find the general solution as homogeneous plus particular. The solution is $N(t)/N_0=e^{-\mu t}(1-\gamma)+\gamma e^{-(\mu+1)t}$ which is integrable from $t=0$ to $\infty$ if $\mu>0$

Answer (score 0):

It checks for me:
\begin{align*}
N(t) &= N_0\frac{e^{-mt}(m+r)-r}{m}, \\
\dot N(t) &= -N_0e^{-mt}(m+r); \\
-mN(t) &= -N_0e^{-mt}(m+r)+rN_0, \\
-mN(t)-rN_0 &= -N_0e^{-mt}(m+r).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks but man this sucks now. It means my equation is not right... Cause i need its integral from 0 to infinity not to diverge